# How to execute a script located in database from Crystal Reports

Tags: javascript, database, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I need to execute a SQL script located in my database, every time I want to print a report from crystal reports. 
I don't know how to do that.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what the problem is. Can you post steps required to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Improved title. Used uppercase where needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have sufficient permissions in your database to create a new Stored Procedure I would recommend creating a Stored Procedure within the database that executes the SQL script.  Then you can just design your Crystal Report using that Stored Procedure as the database.

Answer (score 0):

As R. McMillan recommended you can create a stored procedure and add your script inside. If you do not have permission or you want to keep everything in the report, you can create a command inside the report, run your script code and then return the data to the report.

Answer (score -1):

Crystal alone can't do that.
If you provide the user with your own Crystal Viewer app, you can gain control over the print process.
Or if you are willing to trigger the SQL each time the report is previewed, you can create/get a UFL (User Function Library) that allows you to execute SQL via a Crystal formula.